# wxPhthon Ultimatelistctrl Hyperlink sample code

Tags: hyperlink, wxpython

I need use Ultimatelistctrl to icon with hyperline.

In Ultimatelistctrl API, it mentioned 
"Hyperlink-type items and subitems: they look like an hyperlink, with the proper mouse cursor on hovering;"
But there is no working sample.

I create below render code. DrawSubItem function is called success. But OnMouseEvent is never called. 
How can I bind user click to OnMouseEvent function

class CustomizedRenderer(object):

```
def __init__(self, parent, fileName):

    self.parent = parent
    self.fileName = fileName

    self.normalFont = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
    self.normalFont.SetPointSize(self.normalFont.GetPointSize() + 1)        
    self.smallerFont = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)

    self.greyColour = wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_GRAYTEXT)

    fileType = wx.TheMimeTypesManager.GetFileTypeFromExtension(extension)

    bmp = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, "empty_icon.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    bmp = wx.IconFromBitmap(bmp)


    self.icon = bmp
    self.description = convert(fileType.GetDescription())

def OnMouseEvent(self, e):
    if e.LeftUp():
        webbrowser.open_new("http://www.google.com")
    e.Skip()

def DrawSubItem(self, dc, rect, line, highlighted, enabled):

    ***********************


def GetLineHeight(self):

    ***********************


def GetSubItemWidth(self):

    ***********************
```

I am able to make it works after change C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.5-msw\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py

The change is add some logic on ultimatelistctrl.py onMouse() and then call your module code.